# how to insert a folder of text files as an index inside arraylist?

Tags: c#, arraylist

I was wondering if there is some way to insert some folder that contains some text files as an index in an arraylist, for example I created an arraylist named gestures, now I need to access some path that has 4 folders. For example folder up , folder down, folder left and folder right, each folder has some text files from accelerometer . what I want to do is to insert folder up with its data inside index 0 in the arraylist , folder down with its data in index 1 in arraylist and so on .. so is there some way to do this ?
I am using windows form application C#

in case points are not clear . 
- i got some data from accelerometer saved in many text files.
- and i got 4 folders "up,down,left and right" each folder has number of  text files with the data from the accelerometer .
- what i want to do is to store the first folder named "up" which has number of text files which are data from accelerometer in index number "0" in the arraylist or a list and place the folder "down" in index number "1" in the arraylist or list and so on . in order to make some calculations on these data.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use ArrayLists in .NET. ArrayLists are untyped (i.e. typed as `object`). Better use an array for fixed size collections and a `List<T>` when the required size is not known in advance.

For instance, you could have an array of lists. Each array entry would represent one of your four folders and contain a list of files.

```
List<string>[] files = new List<string>[4]; // This creates the array.
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    files[i] = new List<string>(); // Create the empty lists
}
```

Know you can add files like this:

```
files[0].Add(someFile);
```

---

If you have a variable number of folders use a list of string arrays (since `Directory.GetFiles()` yields an array of strings).

```
List<string[]> files = new List<string[]>(); // Create the outer list.
foreach (string folder in Directory.GetDirectories(baseFolder)) {
     files.Add(Directory.GetFiles(folder));
}
```

---

Instead of storing the file path as `string` you could also store a `FileInfo` object for each file (`List<FileInfo>[]`). `FileInfo` gives you a lot of information on a file like its length or file date and provides methods for file manipulation.

Yet another possibility is to store just `DirectoryInfo` objects and to read the files dynamically:

```
DirectoryInfo[] folders = new DirectoryInfo[4];
folders[0] = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Data\folder up");

foreach (FileInfo file in folders[0].EnumerateFiles())
{
    DoSomethingWith(file);
}
```

Comment: the problem is that i dont want to define some index i mean right now i have 4 gestures folders up, down, left and right but what if i wanted to add more gestures . i want the program to read all folders in the path

Comment: Then make a list of lists `List<List<string>>`.

Comment: how can that be applied to the codes above please ?

Comment: in case you didnt get me right , i just need to put all text in folder up in index 0 and all text in folder down in index 1 and so on whether in an arraylist or list

Comment: So you don't want to stores file names but files contents, i.e. texts? If yes, how? As one string containing all the text or as an array of text lines? Your question is very unclear about this (and that's why you probably got downvoted). Also do you need to store the folder names and file names as well? Please edit your question and clarify these points.

Comment: yes i need the content and this is where i'm stuck actually i dont know how to do that . all i want to do is to move the accelerometer up then the program should tell me its similar to text file "up1.text" in folder "up"  and so on , because im making a DTW program using the accelerometer . hope you got me

Comment: It is still not clear. It seems that you also should remember the folder and file names as well if the program must tell you folder and file names. And what do you mean by similar? What do the files contain exactly? Do you have to compare the text with a given string? In that case even a dictionary would be appropriate. Maybe you should provide a concrete example.